Statistical technique recommendation
Research context:
When you go shopping online, you may originate your shopping from one product but ultimately buy another one.
Research question:
My goal is to understand what advantages the ultimately-bought products have over the originating products that make consumers ultimately buy them and not the originating products. I'm flexible as to how the analysis results could look like but it would be nice to be able to explain this in terms that business people understand, such as:

"In the appliances product category, as the ultimately-bought product's length of warranty increases by 1 year, consumers are more likely to purchase it by 5% compared to the originating product"
"In the cell phone category, for every additional megapixel the ultimately-bought product has, consumers are more likely to purchase it by 12%, which reduces to 4% if it does not have the color variety of the originating product."
"Due to 'anchoring effect', if the price of the originating product is higher than the ultimately-bought product by at least 10%, consumers are more likely to buy the latter even if its avg customer rating is lower by up to 1 point."

Data:
My data shows the top 10 products that consumers ultimately bought after viewing each of the 10000s of originating products. A sample of the data is shown below. The rows are originating products' SKUs and the columns are the ultimately-bought SKUs. For, example, when consumers viewed SKU 1001 (first row), they most often ultimately bought SKUs [6039, 6134,4762 4754,4793,3144,4456,8146,8237,2754]

For each SKU, I have data on several dozens of product features such as price, average customer rating, year released, payment plans, color varieties, etc.
My question: what statistical techniques and methods I should look into to answer this research question by comparing the features of the products viewed vs those ultimately bought?

Are attributes well-defined across all choice sets? Or do you have people looking at a TV initially who go on to buy a fridge, making the most product attributes uncomparable? Do you have quantity data (how many 6039s actually sold) or just a ranking (6039 is top 1, 6134 is top 2,...) or an unranked list? Do you have the number of views by product?

@dimitriy, thank you. The ultimately-bought products are in the same product category as the originating product. So, they share most, if not all, of their attributes. The top 10 ultimately-bought list is ranked but I don't have individual sales data to tell the interval between the ranks. I can somewhat estimate that based on the SKU's number of customer reviews though.  No, I don't have data on views. Looking forward to hearing your ideas :)



In your data, does the same SKU ever appear on both the "bought" and "viewed" side of things?  A place I would start is to determine which product has the highest frequency of being bought after being viewed.


Do you have price/cost information for each SKU?  There's a philosophical quibble about whether cost is just another attribute, but factoring in cost versus features would be part of any practical analysis of this kind of problem.



@NaiveBayesian, thank you. #1 is a great question. Yes, the same SKU can appear on both sides. No, it's a retailer's public data so they don't publish sensitive info like costs of items.

I would work in a stochastic matrix framework. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix

@krkeane That could show the probability of a SKU being bought after having viewed another SKU. But how could the role of the SKU attribute be incorporated in this?

I would try to use a series of rank-ordered probit models with this data: one for each product category.
Here's an example. Suppose you have $1,\dots,J$ alternative products in the TV category. $J$ is a count of distinct SKUs in the Bought columns for TVs. The landing product is indexed by $i=1,...,n$, so $n$ corresponds to the number of distinct SKUs in the Viewed column. Let the aggregated latent utility of product $j$ for folks who first saw product $i$ be given by
$$\eta_{ij} = \mathbf{x}_{ij}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{z_i\alpha_j} + \xi_{ij}$$
Here, the $\mathbf{x}_{ij}$ are the alternative-specific independent variables. For example, you might have price $p_j$ or screen size $s_j$. The $\mathbf{z}_i$ are case-specific variables. Here, a case is a purchase occasion that begins with landing on item $i$. The characteristics of initially viewed items belong here. For example, if you have $p_i$--the price of the landing product-you will get $J-1$ coefficients that give you the substitution effect of the initial product price for each of the alternatives. The marginal effects of these coefficients will give you a sense of which characteristics of product $i$ are really important for choosing a particular alternative. These variables will also give you $J-1$ alternative intercepts.  The $\mathbf{\xi}_{i}'=(\xi_{i,1},...,\xi_{i,J}) \sim \mathtt{MVN}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Omega})$, so the utility shocks are mean zero with covariance $\Omega$. The shocks are the random part of the model. You can make assumptions about the structure of the $j \times j$ covariance matrix.
You can assume that for each of the $i$th landing items, you observe a rank of the alternatives in order of their numeric indices, $\mathbf{y}_i = (J, J-1,\dots,1)$, so the first is the most preferred alternative, and the last is the least preferred alternative.
If a TV model appears in the top-10 list for landing item $m$ but not $p$, its rank will be censored to 11+ in the latter case. This lets you relax the assumption that all $J$ products are ranked for every landing product $i$.
You can then difference adjacent utilities such that
$$\begin{align}
v_{ik} &= \eta_{i,k+1} - \eta_{i,k}  \\
& =(\mathbf{x}_{i,k+1}-\mathbf{x}_{i,k})\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{z}_i(\mathbf{\alpha}_{k+1}-\mathbf{\alpha}_{k})+ (\xi_{i,k+1}-\xi_{i,k}) \\
& = \mathbf{\delta}_{ik}\mathbf{\beta} + \mathbf{z_i} \mathbf{\gamma_k}+\epsilon_{ik} \\
& = \lambda_{ik} + \epsilon_{ik}
\end{align}
$$
for $k=1,\dots,J-1$ and $\mathbf{\epsilon}_i =  (\epsilon_{i1},\ldots,\epsilon_{i,J-1}) \sim \mathtt{MVN}(0,\Sigma_{(i)})$. Here, $\Sigma$ is indexed by landing product $i$ because it is specific to the ranking originating from that event. You can crank through some math to show that
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(\mathbf{y}_i) & = \Pr(v_{i1} \le 0,\ldots,v_{i,J-1} \le 0) \\
&= Pr(\epsilon_{i,1} \le -\lambda_{i1},\ldots,\epsilon_{i,J-1} \le -\lambda_{i,J-1}) \\
& = (2 \pi)^{-(J-1)/2} \left| \mathbf{\Sigma}_{(i)} \right|^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda_{i,1}} \ldots \int_{-\infty}^{-\lambda_{i,J-1}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{z}' \mathbf{\Sigma}_{(i)}^{-1} \mathbf{z} \, d\mathbf{z} \right)
\end{align}
$$
The intuition is that folks who land on product $i$ will purchase product $J$ most often (so it ranks first) if all the other alternatives give relatively lower utility.
You can evaluate this integral numerically using simulation. Ties in ranks can create annoying complications, but luckily, you don't have that here.
Since you have some initial items with more views than others, frequency weights might make sense here to give those cases more weight.
The bad news is that rank-ordered choice models can be hard to estimate with too many alternatives and slow to converge. I assume you do not have too many top-10 TVs, which seems reasonable since most product sales are long-tailed.
Typically, this sort of model is applied to individual choice data. Yours is more aggregated. I don't know how big of a problem this creates, though it changes the interpretation.
A good reference for ranked order choice models is Chapter 18 of Hensher, David A., John M. Rose, and William H. Greene. Applied Choice Analysis. 2nd ed. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2015.


My question: what statistical techniques and methods I should look into ...?

Expanded comments -
I don't work in this domain (product sales analysis).  As a non-expert commentator in the bleachers, I make the following general comments that may or may not be reasonable in your research.
Collect the transition count data underlying the $10,000 \times 11$ matrix of indicies
$\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
    i_{\text{1, viewed SKU}} & i_{\text{1, #1 SKU bought}} & \dots  &  i_{\text{1, #10 SKU bought}} \\
    \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
    i_{\text{10 000+, viewed SKU}} & i_{\text{10 000+, #1 SKU bought}} & \dots  &  i_{\text{10 000+, #10 SKU bought}} 
\end{bmatrix}~.
$
The matrix of indices you mention obscures the relative probability of both the viewed SKUs and the bought SKUs.
Keeping summary data from the trajectory level, I would suggest counting transitions from first-viewed-SKU to a terminal-state (SKU-bought or bought-nothing).
The counts can be stored in an efficient sparse matrix format (from-state, to-state, count). Conceptually, you still have a transition matrix, 10,000 from-SKU rows $\times$ (10,000 to-SKU-viewed + 10,000 to-SKU-bought + nothing-bought) columns. If this is ridiculously huge, perhaps the Markov chain can be decomposed into sub-graphs that may be analyzed separately (e.g., if no significant transition probability between view-swimsuits and bought-farm-tractors, split the data into subsets).
To the transition matrix, I would append an attribute matrix where rows represent distinct attributes (coded 0 or 1, only need to enumerate 1s in sparse format) and columns represent SKU-viewed and SKU-bought.  Hitting this augmented matrix with singular value decomposition (SVD), you will be able to find row groupings of from-SKUs and SKU-attributes extracting characteristic next states; and, column groupings of to-SKU-viewed, to_SKU-bought, and bought-nothing extracting characteristic from states and SKU-attributes. Finally, SVD may suggest further ways for you to decompose your analysis.

Response to @LearningScholar comment

please expand ... so I can understand it better even before reading that chapter you linked?

As explained by Wall, Rechtsteiner and Rocha, SVD is a data reduction technique.  The artifacts from applying SVD to matrix $X$ are three matrices,  $X = U S V^{\textrm{T}}$. $U$ contains characteristic columns, diagonal $S$ contains scale information, and $V^{\textrm{T}}$ contains characteristic rows.
The columns of $U$ and the rows of $V^{\textrm{T}}$ are sorted, describing the most prevalent patterns first. A terse summary (low rank approximation) of the matrix would use only the first few columns of $U$ and the first few rows of $V^{\textrm{T}}$,
$$
X_{m \times n} \approx \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k ~\ll~ \min\left(m,n\right)} u_i ~ s_{i,i} ~ v_i^{\textrm{T}} ~.
$$
In context of your question, if you have SKU-view data for an ivory pillow, a cream pillow, an ecru pillow, a beige pillow, a khaki pillow and a sand pillow, the SVD analysis may find that these six SKUs exhibit similar patterns of high and low values across the SKU-bought columns; and, there may be sets of attributes exhibiting similar SKU-bought patterns, providing candidate groupings for subject matter experts to label.
Enjoy the article!

Can you add a snippet ?

I don't know your programming language of choice.  A rank 5 approximation to a $600 \times 465$ image using R code is shown here.

Thank you very much for this insightful answer. Could you please expand that last paragraph in your post so I can understand it better even before reading that chapter you linked? I especially don't get this part: "you will be able to find row groupings of from-SKUs and SKU-attributes extracting characteristic next states; and, column groupings of to-SKU-viewed, to_SKU-bought, and bought-nothing extracting characteristic from states and SKU-attributes". Can you add a snippet of the output I would get from hitting the augmented matrix with SVD?
